# java.security.KeyStoreException: TrustedCertEntry not supported

Tags: ssl-certificate, java, certificate-authority, pki, keystore

I am trying to secure my private docker registry using SSL encryption. According to [this](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#get-a-certificate), I need to copy a `.crt` and `.key` to a `/certs` directory and it will work.

What I have now is a `.csr`, `.keystore` and `.cer` and a `root ca`, `intermediate certificate`.

I used `Java Keytool` to generate `.csr` and `keystore` and CA gave me `.cer`, `root ca` and `intermediate certificate`.

Now according to link mentioned above, I specifically need `.crt` and `.key`.

What I did that

1. I imported `root certificate (root ca)`, `intermediate certificat` and    `received signed certificate (.cer)` into `keystore`

   `keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias rootca -file Primary.pem -keystore   hostname.keystore`

   `keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias intermediate -file Secondary.pem -keystore  hostname.keystore`

   `keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias hostname -file cert.cer -keystore   hostname.keystore`

   where `Primary.pem` and `Secondary.pem` are Root and Intermediate certificates  respectively and `cert.cer` is received signed certificate and  `hostname.keystore` is keystore used.
2. Then I tried to generate `.key` and `.crt` from `hostname.keystore` by first converting it into `PKCS12` as described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/715827/how-to-generate-key-and-crt-file-from-jks-file-for-httpd-apache-server?rq=1) but after the first step, I got following error

   `Problem importing entry for alias rootca: java.security.KeyStoreException: TrustedCertEntry not supported`

   See below for command and error:

   `keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore hostname.keystore -destkeystore hostname.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12`

   `Enter destination keystore password:
   Enter source keystore password:`

   `Problem importing entry for alias rootca: java.security.KeyStoreException: TrustedCertEntry not supported.
   Entry for alias rootca not imported.
   Do you want to quit the import process? [no]:  no`

   `Problem importing entry for alias intermediate: java.security.KeyStoreException: TrustedCertEntry not supported.
   Entry for alias intermediate not imported.
   Do you want to quit the import process? [no]:  no`

   `Existing entry alias domain exists, overwrite? [no]:  yes
   Entry for alias domain successfully imported.`

   `Problem importing entry for alias hostname: java.security.KeyStoreException: TrustedCertEntry not supported.
   Entry for alias hostname not imported.
   Do you want to quit the import process? [no]:  no`

   `Import command completed:  1 entries successfully imported, 3 entries failed or cancelled`
3. How to solve this issue and secure the registry? Is it related to Java   version?

Platform: RHEL 4.1

Java Version: 1.7.0_75

Comment: (updated) First `keytool -importcert` the server (EE) cert `cert.cer` to the **same alias** that you used to generate the **keypair and the CSR** (certreq); `hostname` is apparently NOT the correct alias. It should say `Certificate reply was installed` and NOT `Certificate was added`. Second specify that alias in the `keytool -importkeystore` like `-srcalias foo`.

Comment: I changed the alias as you said and it said `Certificate reply was installed` and then checked the content of my keystore `keytool -list -keystore hostname.keystore`. Output was        `Your keystore contains 3 entries

rootca, Oct 17, 2016, trustedCertEntry,                                    intermediate, Oct 17, 2016, trustedCertEntry,                                                                        
hostname, Oct 18, 2016, PrivateKeyEntry`                                                               But the error is still same when I convert it into `PKCS12`

Comment: Also, when I again do `keytool -importcert` the `cert.cer` using same alias, it says `keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Certificate reply and certificate in keystore are identical`. Also instead of three, keystore should have four entries, one private key and three certificates (rootca, intermediate and cert.cer). Isn't it?

Comment: Java 7 does not allow a trustedCert entry in a PKCS12 keystore, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614239/pkcs12-java-keystore-from-ca-and-user-certificate-in-java. You can try with OpenSSL `openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey privateKey.key -in certificate.crt -certfile CACert.crt`

Comment: No, you don't need or want a trustedCertEntry for the server cert; the server cert is PART OF the PrivateKeyEntry which apparently is named `hostname` in spite of your posted log identifying that as a trustedCert. In fact rereading your log I see it says `domain` _was_ converted. Are these the actual aliases or are you redacting them for posting? If so, it looks like you've messed them up. If the PrivateKeyEntry is in fact named `hostname` then `-importkeystore ... -deststoretype pkcs12` !!WITH `-srcalias hostname`!! should work.

Comment: Adding for completeness: you don't really need trustedCert entries for root and intermediate either; they are _copied_ into the privatekey entry, which you can see with `-list -v`. However, that approach is a little more complicated, and you're having enough trouble with the simple method I didn't want to confuse you.

Comment: Yes, I imported `cert.cer` with correct alias and output of `keytool -list -keystore hostname.keystore` is                                                       `Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 3 entries

rootcaca, Oct 17, 2016, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 
intermediate, Oct 17, 2016, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 
hostname, Oct 18, 2016, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1):`

Comment: I think now it is correctly imported and should work.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks a lot!! I appreciate your help very much. It is working fine now. :)